# Why does a curve in projective space "look like" a sphere?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Whenever I read about curves in $\Bbb{P}^2(\Bbb{C})$, I am asked to imagine them to be spheres. However, I do not have a good idea of why they should be spheres. I know, that $\Bbb{P}^1(\Bbb{C})$ looks like a sphere. Does the fact that a curve too looks like a sphere follow from the fact that most curves are isomorphic to $\Bbb{P}^1(\Bbb{C})$?

Comment: Who asked you to do that? They should not have! In fact, if you read _Moduli of Curves_ by Harris--Morrison, somewhere in Chapter 1 they advocate precisely the opposite: even though complex curves are real 2-manifolds (at most points), we should draw them like real 1-manifolds. The advantage of this is that you can actually draw things that look like they are intersecting transversely.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand this claim; it's certainly not true that most curves are isomorphic to the projective line. Smooth projective curves of [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)) $g$ are $g$-holed tori, and for curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ infinitely many values of $g$ are possible (given by the [genus-degree formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus%E2%80%93degree_formula)); for more on this see any textbook on Riemann surfaces.